# how to check string and numbers to converting an array

Tags: php

I have a php code to convert an array to json:

```
$output = array(
    'name' => "annie",
    'is_bool' => 1,
    'total_amount' => '431.65',
    'phone_number' => '0272561313'
);
    
echo json_encode($output,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

but `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` removed 0 numbers at first value.

I want this output:

```
{"name":"annie","is_bool":1,"total_amount":431.65,"phone_number":0272561313}
```

my `$output` initial of a query of database.

Comment: Your desired output makes no sense. Phone numbers are not "numbers" in a mathematical sense, and anything reading `0272561313` in a JSON value _will_ see it as the number "272 million, 561 thousand, 3 hundred and 13". So your real problem becomes "how to convert some values to numbers and leave others as strings".

Comment: @S.M_Emamian Remove JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK (and optionally assign the value to 'total_amount' as a number instead of a string).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no way to do what you're trying to do with a PHP number.

The leading zero on the phone number won't be respected if it's cast to a float or integer. Neither will country codes, such as +44.

Cast it as a string; it's all you can do.
So:

```
$output = [
    //Don't mix your quote types please, it makes baby Jesus cry.
    'name' => 'annie',
    //Shouldn't this be a boolean? JSON will handle it perfectly well
    'is_bool' => 1,
    //Let's cast explicitly to float here, just-in-case
    'total_amount' => (float) 431.65,
    ///Leave this as a string
    'phone_number' => '0272561313'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This part makes no sense:

```
"phone_number":0272561313
```

There is no point in adding leading zeros to numbers, any decent library used to parse the resulting JSON will automatically remove them, because that is how numbers work. Phone numbers are called numbers partly for historial reasons (from the era before telephone exchanges were fully automated), partly because it's informal English.

I suspect what you really want is to de-stringify some known numeric fields:

```
array_walk(
    $output,
    static function (mixed &$value, string $key) {
        if ($key === 'total_amount' && is_string($value)) {
            $value = (float)$value;
        }
    },
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

```
{"name":"annie","is_bool":1,"total_amount":431.65,"phone_number":"0272561313"}
```